# django restframework object-level-validation

Tags: django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

These are my models : Test, Skillarea, question

**MODELS.PY** :

```
class Test(BaseModel):

    types = models.ManyToManyField(
        TestType,
        related_name='tests',
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class SkillArea(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test = models.ForeignKey('Test', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='skill_areas')
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'assessment.Question',
        related_name='skill_areas',
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class Question(BaseModel):
   
    question_text = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        self.get_type_display()

    def __str__(self):
        return truncatewords(self.question_text, 7)
```

```
class TestType(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to have an updateserializer for updating, but the field "type" in the Test model, only can be updated if there is no question in Skillarea model which related to Test model( has the same id as updating test, in its test field)

I wrote these serializer and view but it doesnt know `data['id']` which i used in validator and sends `KeyError: 'id'`

**serializer.py :**

```
class TestUpdateAPIViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, data):
        questions = SkillArea.objects.filter(test=data['id'], questions__isnull=False)
        if questions.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You may not edit type")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = (

            'id',
            'types',
            'title',
            'summary',
          
        )
```

**Views.py :**

```
class TestUpdateAPIView(APIView):

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        test = Test.active_objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = TestUpdateAPIViewSerializer(instance=test, partial=True, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the `id` from `instance` attribute.

```
class TestUpdateAPIViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, data):
        questions = SkillArea.objects.filter(test=self.instance.id, questions__isnull=False)
        ...
```